# Aggregate for repeated records SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to count customer in different branches  in a query and must be showed customers at result. I want to below result:

```
Branch Cust_id Count_cust_per_branch
1        1000       3
1        2000       3
1        3000       3
____________
2        4000       4
2        5000       4
2        7000       4
2        8000       4
```

Count_cust_per_branch is a measure that count of customers each branch

Comment: What's wrong with `COUNT`..?

Comment: Use the [edit] feature.

Comment: It’s not wrong, your script is correct  completely , I want to execute this script on huge table. When I executed that return result about 1 hr . I asked you how can I maintenance this query for getting result in short time

Comment: I think that comment was meant to go on the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```sql
COUNT(Cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch) as Count_cust_per_branch
```

to count the number of customers in each branch while also having a record for each `Cust_id` and branch.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks ggordon your answer is correct but for getting result in huge table is so slow

Comment: Please upvote if you found the answer useful. Can you update the question with an image of your query plan (see [how to here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15)) and your full sql from running the query to better assist with looking at ways to optimize the query?